# Correlation matrix with significance test custom function not working

Tags: r, r-corrplot, hmisc

I tried using the custom function (flattenCorrMatrix) mentioned in link below but its showing up with an error. I have never seen this kind of error before, and haven't worked with functions in R so hoping someone can help fix it.
I am also finding that I have to assign the correlation values to a different variable to call it using corrplot. This comes up with an additional warning message. The warning is ok, since I know the plot is correct, but is there a way to get rid of the error and the warning? I have attached my code and data file used too. Thanks!

**Link from where I got my code:**
http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-a-quick-start-guide-to-analyze-format-and-visualize-a-correlation-matrix-using-r-software

**Error for customer function:**
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 36, 28

**Warning message for corrplot:**
Warning message:
In corrplot(cr3, type = "lower", p.mat = cr4$P, sig.level = 0.1,  :
p.mat and corr may be not paired, their rownames and colnames are not totally same!

**My Code:**

```
library(corrplot)
library(Hmisc)

#load data set including 2016-2021 data (without replicates from 2016-17)
crop.data4 <- read.csv("barleygt20.csv", header = TRUE)
variables<-crop.data4[,c(6:15)]

#calculate correlations
cr1<-cor(variables)
cr2=rcorr(as.matrix(variables))
colnames(cr1)<-c("Yield", "Protein", "Weight", "Plump", "Thin", "Onset GT", "Peak GT", "Offset GT", "Onset-Peak GT", "Peak-Offset GT")
rownames(cr1)<-c("Yield", "Protein", "Weight", "Plump", "Thin", "Onset GT", "Peak GT", "Offset GT", "Onset-Peak GT", "Peak-Offset GT")

flattenCorrMatrix <- function(cormat, pmat) 
{
  ut <- upper.tri(cormat)
  data.frame(
    row = rownames(cormat)[row(cormat)[ut]],
    column = rownames(cormat)[col(cormat)[ut]],
    cor  =(cormat)[ut],
    p = pmat[ut]
  )
}
flattenCorrMatrix(cr2$r, cr2$P)

# Correlation plot with insignificant correlations crossed out
corrplot(cr1, type="lower",p.mat = cr2$P, sig.level = 0.05, tl.col="black", method="color", title= "A", mar=c(0,0,1,0))
```

**Data file used:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gTgrtsrctEVevJeP-sgKdtjvT707eEcX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I get the warning and error showed when I use the `corrplot` and not the `flattenCorrMatrix` (which works fine).  Maybe you meant `corrplot`?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the `diag`onal values in 'cr2$P' which are `NA` whereas the one in 'cr1' is 1.  This creates an imbalance in the length if the missing values are removed.  The warning occurs because the `dimnames` are slightly different.

```
> diag(cr1)
   yield  protein  onsetgt   peakgt offsetgt  donpeak doffpeak     mgwt    plump     thin 
       1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1 
> diag(cr2$P)
   yield  protein  onsetgt   peakgt offsetgt  donpeak doffpeak     mgwt    plump     thin 
      NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA 

> dimnames(cr1)
[[1]]
 [1] "Yield"          "Protein"        "Weight"         "Plump"          "Thin"           "Onset GT"       "Peak GT"        "Offset GT"     
 [9] "Onset-Peak GT"  "Peak-Offset GT"

[[2]]
 [1] "Yield"          "Protein"        "Weight"         "Plump"          "Thin"           "Onset GT"       "Peak GT"        "Offset GT"     
 [9] "Onset-Peak GT"  "Peak-Offset GT"

> dimnames(cr2$P)
[[1]]
 [1] "yield"    "protein"  "onsetgt"  "peakgt"   "offsetgt" "donpeak"  "doffpeak" "mgwt"     "plump"    "thin"    

[[2]]
 [1] "yield"    "protein"  "onsetgt"  "peakgt"   "offsetgt" "donpeak"  "doffpeak" "mgwt"     "plump"    "thin"
```

---

One option is to set the `diag`onal to `NA` and the `dimnames` as the other one

```
diag(cr1) <- NA
dimnames(cr2$P) <- dimnames(cr1)
```

and now we apply the code

```
corrplot(cr1, type="lower",p.mat = cr2$P, sig.level = 0.05,
    tl.col="black", method="color", title= "A", mar=c(0,0,1,0))
```